# Host can't communicate with hyper-v VM

Tags: networking, virtualization, ip, hyper-v

I can't ping/ssh from the host to the VM or the other way around.

I'm running a Ubuntu virtual machine on a Windows 10 host with hyper-v.

I'm using a internal virtual switch with hyper-v. The VM has a static ip address and I'm not allowed to change that. So I've assigned the network adapter a static ip too. The host and VM can ping to the network adapter but can't ping to each other now.

I'm new at this and don't know what seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> host and VM can ping to the network adapter

If you can reach the adapter you reached your destination. Do you mean some sort of router/gateway?

If possible disable the Firewall on both host and VM and see if the pings get through.

AFAIK there's also an option on the Virtual Network Adapters that prevents the host from accessing that connection. This could also prevent your host from reaching